# PHP Header application/x-javascript in all JS files?

Tags: php, header

my question is simple, can I do not have any .js file in my website, just php with header, like this?

```
Header("content-type: application/x-javascript");
```

why? to protect my .js files, prevent direct access.

Can I? or it will make my website slower?

thank you!

Comment: You are aware that this will do nothing to protct your source code? JS will be loaded into the browser and anyone can stop the program flow via firebug etc to look into the code.

Comment: Either a browser is able to download and execute Javascript or it's not. You cannot "protect" your Javascript files, yet wish to execute the Javascript code in the browser. You have a case of cognitive dissonance.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to have a acceptable result is to parse (compress) the js code, but since there are programs with autoformat this is useless aswell.

But i found i solution that works fine for me, 
First use:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="_js/script.php"></script>
```

then in you script.php you will be able to make a check for example if a session variable is set then you use you header with the content-type and just echo all the js. Works fine for me.